# How do I get an SPSite from SPWebEventProperties?

Tags: event-handlers, spsite

How do I get an `SPSite` object from the `SPWebEventProperties` object passed into the `SPWebEventReceiver.WebProvisioned` method?

```
public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
```

Comment: Never mind. It was silly. SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to create a new `SPSite` object. Instead use:

```
properties.Web.Site
```

Answer (score 2):

This MSDN article [Security Best Practices for Developers in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552614.aspx) recommends against constructing SPSite objects using a Guid.

> Construct SPSite Objects Safely
>
> The Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite
>   constructor is prone to the following
>   two problems:
>
> New SPSite objects can be constructed by using a fully qualified
>   domain name, for example
>   http://contoso1.example.com. If this
>   domain name is different from the
>   current request context, it can lead
>   to a cross-domain security issue.
>
> New SPSite objects can be constructed by using a site identifier
>   (ID) and optional user token, but
>   without a fully qualified URL or
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUrlZone
>   enumeration. If the current request
>   context is not the Default zone, this
>   can bypass web application policy.

It would be safer to use

```
properties.Web.Site
```

as advised by Anders